# Asp.Net MVC 3 (Razor, Json, Ajax) Master Detail - detail save failing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to MVC3 and trying to build a simple Invoicing app. The problem with my code is that the Ajax Post is failing and I cant find out why. Stepped through the JQuery code and it seems fine but by the time the POST hits the controller, the Model.IsValid is false. The problem seems to be with the child records. The invoice Master record is being saved to the DB but the InvoiceRow isnt. The problem lies in the SaveInvoice() function.

```
 public class Invoice
{
    [Key]
    public int InvoiceID { get; set; }

    public int ContractID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Invoice Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}")]
    public DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Invoice No")]
    public int InvoiceNumber { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Payment Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}")]
    public DateTime PaymentDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Contract Contract { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<InvoiceRow> InvoiceRows { get; set; }
}

public class InvoiceRow
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int InvoiceID { get; set; }
    public string RowDetail { get; set; }
    public int RowQty { get; set; }
    public decimal ItemPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal RowTotal { get; set; }

    public virtual Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
}


public class InvoiceController : Controller
{
    private CyberneticsContext db = new CyberneticsContext();

    //
    // GET: /Invoice/

    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        var invoices = db.Invoices.Include(i => i.Contract);
        return View(invoices.ToList());
    }

    //
    // GET: /Invoice/Details/5

    public ViewResult Details(int id)
    {
        Invoice invoice = db.Invoices.Find(id);
        return View(invoice);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Invoice/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Create";
        ViewBag.ContractID = new SelectList(db.Contracts, "Id", "ContractName");
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Invoice/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Create(Invoice invoice)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (invoice.InvoiceID > 0)
                {
                    var invoiceRows = db.InvoiceRows.Where(ir => ir.InvoiceID == invoice.InvoiceID);

                    foreach (InvoiceRow row in invoiceRows)
                    {
                        db.InvoiceRows.Remove(row);
                    }

                    foreach (InvoiceRow row in invoice.InvoiceRows)
                    {
                        db.InvoiceRows.Add(row);
                    }

                    db.Entry(invoice).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }
                else
                {
                    db.Invoices.Add(invoice);
                }

                db.SaveChanges();

                return Json(new { Success = 1, InvoiceID = invoice.InvoiceID, ex = "" });
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { Success = 0, ex = ex.Message.ToString() });
        }

        return Json(new { Success = 0, ex = new Exception("Unable to Save Invoice").Message.ToString() });
    }

    //
    // GET: /Invoice/Edit/5

    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
        Invoice invoice = db.Invoices.Find(id);
        ViewBag.ContractID = new SelectList(db.Contracts, "Id", "ContractName", invoice.ContractID);
        return View("Create", invoice);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Invoice/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Invoice invoice)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(invoice).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.ContractID = new SelectList(db.Contracts, "Id", "ContractName", invoice.ContractID);
        return View(invoice);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Invoice/Delete/5

    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        Invoice invoice = db.Invoices.Find(id);
        return View(invoice);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Invoice/Delete/5

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Invoice invoice = db.Invoices.Find(id);
        db.Invoices.Remove(invoice);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
  }
}

@model Cybernetics2012.Models.Invoice

... script tags excluded for brevity

<h2 class="h2">@ViewBag.Title</h2>


<script type="text/javascript">

$( document ).ready( function ()
{
    // here i have used datatables.js (jQuery Data Table)
    $( '.tableItems' ).dataTable
    ( 
        {
            "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
            "oTableTools": { "aButtons": [], "sRowSelect": "single" },
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "bFilter": false,
            "bSort": true,
            "bInfo": false
        }
    );

    // Add DatePicker widget to InvoiceDate textbox
    $( '#InvoiceDate' ).datepicker();

    // Add DatePicker widget to PaymentDate textbox
    $( '#PaymentDate' ).datepicker();

    // Get the tableItems table
    var oTable = $( '.tableItems' ).dataTable();
} );


// this function is used to add item to table
function AddInvoiceItem()
{
    // Adding item to table
    $( '.tableItems' ).dataTable().fnAddData( [$( '#RowDetail' ).val(), $( '#RowQty' ).val(), $( '#ItemPrice' ).val(), $( '#RowQty' ).val() * $( '#ItemPrice' ).val()] );

    // clear text boes after adding data to table..
    $( '#RowDetail' ).val( "" )
    $( '#RowQty' ).val( "" )
    $( '#ItemPrice' ).val( "" )

}


// This function is used to delete selected row from Invoice Rows Table and then set deleted item to Edit text Boxes
function DeleteRow()
{
    // DataTables.TableTools plugin for getting selected row items
    var oTT = TableTools.fnGetInstance( 'tableItems' ); // Get Table instance
    var sRow = oTT.fnGetSelected(); // Get Selected Item From Table

    // Set deleted row item to editable text boxes
    $( '#RowDetail' ).val( $.trim( sRow[0].cells[0].innerHTML.toString() ) );
    $( '#RowQty' ).val( jQuery.trim( sRow[0].cells[1].innerHTML.toString() ) );
    $( '#ItemPrice' ).val( $.trim( sRow[0].cells[2].innerHTML.toString() ) );

    $( '.tableItems' ).dataTable().fnDeleteRow( sRow[0] );
}


//This function is used for sending data(JSON Data) to the Invoice Controller
function SaveInvoice()
{
    // Step 1: Read View Data and Create JSON Object

    // Creating invoicRow Json Object
    var invoiceRow = { "InvoiceID": "", "RowDetail": "", "RowQty": "", "ItemPrice": "", "RowTotal": "" };

    // Creating invoice Json Object
    var invoice = { "InvoiceID": "", "ContractID": "", "InvoiceDate": "", "InvoiceNumber": "", "PaymentDate": "", "InvoiceRows":[] };

    // Set Invoice Value
    invoice.InvoiceID = $( "#InvoiceID" ).val();
    invoice.ContractID = $( "#ContractID" ).val();
    invoice.InvoiceDate = $( "#InvoiceDate" ).val();
    invoice.InvoiceNumber = $( "#InvoiceNumber" ).val();
    invoice.PaymentDate = $( "#PaymentDate" ).val();

    // Getting Table Data from where we will fetch Invoice Rows Record
    var oTable = $( '.tableItems' ).dataTable().fnGetData();

    for ( var i = 0; i < oTable.length; i++ )
    {

        // IF This view is for edit then it will read InvoiceId from Hidden field
        if ( $( 'h2' ).text() == "Edit" )
        {
            invoiceRow.InvoiceID = $( '#InvoiceID' ).val();
        }
        else
        {
            invoiceRow.InvoiceID = 0;
        }

        // Set InvoiceRow individual Value
        invoiceRow.RowDetail = oTable[i][0];
        invoiceRow.RowQty = oTable[i][1];
        invoiceRow.ItemPrice = oTable[i][2];
        invoiceRow.RowTotal = oTable[i][3];           

        // adding to Invoice.InvoiceRow List Item
        invoice.InvoiceRows.push( invoiceRow );

        invoiceRow = { "RowDetail": "", "RowQty": "", "ItemPrice": "", "RowTotal": "" };
    }
    // Step 1: Ends Here


    // Set 2: Ajax Post
    // Here i have used ajax post for saving/updating information
    $.ajax( {
        url: '/Invoice/Create',
        data: JSON.stringify( invoice ),
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json;',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function ( result )
        {
            if ( result.Success == "1" )
            {
                window.location.href = "/Invoice/Index";
            }
            else
            {
                alert( result.ex );
            }
        }
    } );
}

</script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"    type="text/javascript"></script>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Invoice</legend>

    @if (Model != null)
    {
        <input type="hidden" id="InvoiceID" name="InvoiceID" value="@Model.InvoiceID" />
    }


    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContractID, "Contract")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("ContractID", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContractID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InvoiceDate)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InvoiceDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InvoiceDate)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InvoiceNumber)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InvoiceNumber)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InvoiceNumber)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PaymentDate)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PaymentDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PaymentDate)
    </div>
</fieldset>

<br />

<fieldset>
    <legend>Add Invoice Row</legend>
    <br />
    <label>
        Row Detail :</label>
    @Html.TextBox("RowDetail")
    <label>
        Row Qty :</label>
    @Html.TextBox("RowQty", null, new { style = "width:20px;text-align:center" })
    <label>
        Item Price :</label>
    @Html.TextBox("ItemPrice", null, new { style = "width:70px" })

    <input onclick="AddInvoiceItem()" type="button" value="Add Invoice Item" />
    <table id="tableItems" class="tableItems" width="400px">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Detail
                </th>
                <th>
                    Qty
                </th>
                <th>
                    Price
                </th>
                <th>
                    Row Total
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @if (Model != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in Model.InvoiceRows)
                {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(i => item.RowDetail)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(i => item.RowQty)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(i => item.ItemPrice)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(i => item.RowTotal)
                    </td>
                </tr>                       
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br />
    <input onclick="DeleteRow()" type="button" value="Delete Selected Row" />
</fieldset>      

<p>
    <input onclick="SaveInvoice()" type="submit" value="Save Invoice" />
</p>

}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: and how exactly is it failing?

Comment: So I started messing around with the data types and changed all the numeric values to integers and things started working. Changed back the relevant fields to decimals and things started breaking again. The problem is with the invoice rows. Multiplying the unit(int) by unit price (decimal) is somehow breaking something. The Ajax posting of the invoice looks fine in the JQuery code, however, the result is returning a success = 0. When I check the controller, the invoice is showing null value for invoice rows. At a loss how to debug this issue.

Comment: Another thing I noticed is that the Ajax post is hitting the controller 2 times?? Surely Ajax is posting a invoice with child rows so it should only be posting once. Does this have something to do with the rowprice getting calculated by unit* unitprice?? This seems to be a datatype conversion issue.

Comment: I have the project up on skydrive if anyone is willing to look at this for me. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I have found the error but still have no idea how to fix it. It is on the RowTotal field. The error is:The parameter conversion from type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Decimal' failed because no type converter can convert between these types. So, I tried formatting the json object to a float :: invoiceRow.RowTotal = parseFloat( oTable[i][3] ); Still breaks. WTF??? The Ajax post function sends a json object but the controller doesnt receive it. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to examine the Model and extract the errors. With those in hand you can begin fixing the problems that are causing the model binder to fail.

Here's an extension method I use to dump invalid model errors to the output console

http://pastebin.com/S0gM3vqg